# What is the relation between X server and display?

Tags: x11, display

What is the relation between X server and display?

Can multiple X servers  run simultaneously on the same display?

Can a X server   run simultaneously on multiple displays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display is effectively the X server; there is exactly one display per X server. So multiple X servers can’t run simultaneously on the same display, and an X server can’t run simultaneously on multiple displays. (Strictly speaking, the latter point isn’t correct, but I don’t think there’s an X server which can serve multiple displays.)

See the :*displaynumber* description in [the `Xserver` manpage](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/Xserver.1.html), and [the “Display Names” section of the `X` manpage](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/X.7.html#sect4).